# C言語の宣言・型の読み方を教えてください。

Tags: c

つまらない質問で申し訳ございません。

```
int (*load_binary)(struct linux_binprm *, struct pt_regs *regs);
```

これの読み方がわかりません。自分の考えでは、

```
load_binary is pointer to function(struct linux_binprm *, struct pt_regs *regs) returning int.
```

(load_binaryは、引数(struct linux_binprm *, struct pt_regs *regs)をとる関数(戻り値はint) へのポインタ)だと思ったのですが、合ってますか？
だとすると、引数のところの `struct linux_binprm *` で、仮引数が無いように思えるのですが、これはどうゆうことなんでしょう？

どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

関数のプロトタイプ宣言時には仮引数の変数を省略することができるようです。

参照
　https://www.grapecity.com/tools/support/powernews/column/clang/015/page02.htm

なので、実装されている場所には変数名があるのではないでしょうか。
また、load_binaryの考え方については合っていると思います。

Comment: 迅速な回答ありがとうございました。質問文の整形までしてくださってありがとうございます。＾＾；　ところでstackoverflowってお礼システムってないんでしたっけ？

Comment: @hirohumi24 お礼の代わりに役にたった質問や回答には「up vote」を(上向きの△をクリック)、自分の質問が(最終的に)解決した場合は「承認」を使用してください。詳しくは [ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour) も参照してみるとよいでしょう。